# pix2pixHD in cpu mode illegal instruction

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to test pix2pixHD. I don't have a GPU. I am using `pytorch==0.4.1`. I am running the test for cityscape model with the following command:

```
python test.py --name label2city_1024p --netG local --ngf 32 --gpu_ids -1 --resize_or_crop none
```

But I am getting `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`. I tried the backtrace with gdb and found this:

```
#0  0x00007fcd623175e6 in THFloatVector_normal_fill_AVX2 () from /home/momen/nvidia_vid2vid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libcaffe2.so
#1  0x00007fcd621d06f0 in THFloatTensor_normal () from /home/momen/nvidia_vid2vid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libcaffe2.so
#2  0x00007fcd61c85156 in at::CPUFloatType::normal_(at::Tensor&, double, double, at::Generator*) const ()
   from /home/momen/nvidia_vid2vid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/lib/libcaffe2.so
#3  0x00007fcdb8724895 in torch::autograd::VariableType::normal_ (this=0x27d4fc0, self=..., mean=0, std=0.02, generator=0x0)
at torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType.cpp:10819
#4  0x00007fcdb89e6300 in at::Tensor::normal_ (generator=0x0, std=0.02, mean=0, this=0x7fcd921cc958) at /pytorch/torch/lib/tmp_install/include/ATen/TensorMethods.h:700
```

How do I solve this issue? Any type of help is welcome. Thanks.

Additional Info:
I tried py-bt and the problem occurs with `m.weight.data.normal_(0.0, 0.02)` for first `Conv2d` layer.

Comment: did you installed pytorch which is the cpu version ?

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain yeah I did install the cpu version. Also note that problem seems to be with avx2 instruction.

Comment: are you using this repo https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD ?

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain yes.

Comment: did you try this https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD/issues/70 ?
you have to set gpu_ids=1 and the ndo the change in the code.

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain That's a different problem. I am stuck in the initialization.

Comment: are you sure you removed `.cuda()` initialization when the model in initialized ?

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain this has nothing to do with cuda. Anyway I tried your suggestion by removing all .cuda() calls. And it didn't work.